# signal vs variable

Tags: variables, signals, vhdl

VHDL provides two major object types to hold data, namel `signal` and `variable`, but I can't find anywhere that is clear on when to use one data-type over the other.  Can anyone shed some light on their strengths/limitations/scope/synthesis/situations in which using one would be better than the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Signals can be used to communicate values between processes.  Variables cannot.  There are `shared variables` which can in older compilers, but you really are asking for problems (with race conditions) if you do that - unless you use `protected types` which are a bit like classes.  Then they are same to use for communication, but not (as far as I know) synthesisable.

This fundamental restriction on communication comes from the way updates on signals and variables work.

The big distinction comes because variables update immediately they are assigned to (with the `:=` operator).  Signals have an update *scheduled* when assigned to (with the `<=` operator) but the value that anyone sees when they read the signal will not change until some time passes.

(Aside: That amount of time could be as small as a delta cycle, which is the smallest amount of time in a VHDL simuator - no "real" time passes.  Something like `wait for 0 ps;` causes the simulator to wait for the next delta cycle before continuing.)

If you need the same logic to feed *into* multiple flipflops a variable is a good way of factoring that logic into a single point, rather than copying/pasting code.

In terms of logic, within a clocked process, signals always infer a flipflop.  Variables can be used for both combinatorial logic and inferring a flipflop.  Sometimes both for the same variable.  Some think this confusing, personally, I think it's fine:

```
process (clk)
  variable something : std_logic;
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    if reset = '1' then
       something := '0';
    else
       output_b <= something or input c; -- using the previous clock's value of 'something' infers a register
       something := input_a and input_b; -- comb. logic for a new value
       output_a <= something or input_c; -- which is used immediately, not registered here
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

One thing to watch using variables is that because if they are read after they are written, no register output is used, you can get long chains of logic which can lead to missing your fmax target

One thing to watch using signals (in clocked processes) is that they always infer a register, and hence leads to latency.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said signals get updated with their new value at the end of the time slice, but variables are updated immediately.

```
// inside some process
// varA = sigA = 0. sigB = 2
varA := sigB + 1;      // varA is now 3
sigC <= varA + 1;      // sigC will be 4

sigA <= sigB + 1;      // sigA will be 3
sigD <= sigA + 1;      // sigD will be 1 (original sigA + 1)
```

For hardware design, I use variables very infrequently. It's normally when I'm hacking in some feature that really needs the code to be re-factored, but I'm on a deadline. I avoid them because I find the mental model of working with signals and variables too different to live nicely in one piece of code. That's not to say it can't be done, but I think most RTL engineers avoid mixing... and you can't avoid signals.

Other points:

- Signals have entity scoping. Variables are local to the process.
- Both synthesize

Comment: It's fine if you don't use variables, but many engineers use them all the time. One public example is the GRLIB/LEON3, which is used in aerospace applications.

Comment: Fair enough, everyone has their styles. I tend to move around a fair bit as I contract and I was just basing my comments on the observations I've made. Nothing inherently 'wrong' with using them.